# Create a random quiz mode where every array part is only called once

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I'm a bit new to Android Studio and I want to make small quiz app. On the start screen, there are two buttons. With the first button, you just click through your questions and you can start at a specific question number if you want (this is already working). With the second button, I wand to create a random mode BUT every question should only be asked once. So there should not be the possibility to get the same questions twice.

For that I created an Array:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> questionsDone = new ArrayList<>();
```

And got the lenght of the Question Array:

```
public int maxQuestions = QuestionLibrary.nQuestions.length;
```

then I have a function for updating the question:

```
private void updateQuestion(){

    //RANDOM MODE
    if (startNumber == -1) {
        if (questionsDone.size() >= maxQuestions) {
            finishQuiz();
        } else {
            nQuestionNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (maxQuestions));

            do {
                if (questionsDone.contains(nQuestionNumber)) {
                    nQuestionNumber = nQuestionNumber - 1;
                    if (nQuestionNumber == -1) {
                        nQuestionNumber = maxQuestions-1;
                    }
                } else {
                    questionsDone.add(nQuestionNumber);
                    notDone = true;
                }

            } while (notDone = false);
        }
    }
    nQuestionView.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(nQuestionNumber));
    nButtonChoice1.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(nQuestionNumber));
    nButtonChoice2.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(nQuestionNumber));
    nButtonChoice3.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(nQuestionNumber));
```

So my idea was that when I start random mode, I pass the value "-1". If the size of the array (questions were done) equals the number of the available questions the quiz should stop. If not, I just get a random number and multiply it by the number of questions. Then there is a do-while function which makes sure that if the questionsDone-Array already contains the number it will get a new number and after getting a number which is not in the array it will be stored in the array.

This is what the app does when I click on random mode:

It always shows a random question but sometimes one questions are asked twice and more. And suddenly it stops (the app is loading the result page) but the stop does not come with a pattern. When I have 7 questions, each question is minimum asked once and sometimes it stops after 15, sometimes after 20 questions and so on.

Does someone know why?

Comment: Your approach seems fine, but in cases like this you may want to make it easier. Just duplicate your "normal" mode but before starting asking questions, "shuffle" the order. See `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(nQuestions);
Collections.shuffle(list);`

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. So you don't see any mistake in my code?

About your code:
the "nQuestions" in the brackets is the Array which contains the questions right?

Edit: Ahhh, I think I understand now. The nQuestions in your case is the total number of questions and then you call a random number.

Comment: Didn't get into your code but I thought you are complicating yourself. If you already have working code, just reuse that :) Your random mode should just shuffle the questions, you can either shuffle the questions (I understand that's what QuestionLibrary.nQuestions is) or you can just get a shuffled array of question indices.

Comment: Ok but right now I don't have an array of question indices. I have a question library (nQuestionLibrary) with a certain length and I have a nQuestionNumber which the number of the question getting called next. So I would have to create a new array which contains the indices?

Comment: So I created an Array with shuffled indices:

    if (startNumber == -1) {
            Integer i = 0;

            do {
                questionsDone.add(i);
                i++;
            }while (i < maxQuestions);

            Collections.shuffle(questionsDone);
        }

and every time the question gets updated I'm calling the next indices:

if (startNumber == -1) {
            if (j>=4){
                finishQuiz();
            }else {
                nQuestionNumber = questionsDone.get(j);
                j++;
            }
        }
I'll inform you if it works

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted to give an update to both of you, I posted an anwser. Thank you guys for the good input. It works now and this is how I got it working:

First I created an array:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> availableQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then i put integers in the array starting by 0 and ending maxQuestions-1 and I shuffled the values:

```
if (startNumber == -1) {
        Integer i = 0;

        do {
            availableQuestions.add(i);
            i++;
        }while (i < maxQuestions);

        Collections.shuffle(availableQuestions);
    }
```

Then on every button click this function starts to work (j was declared as an integer with the value 0 before):

```
 if (startNumber == -1) {
            nQuestionNumber = availableQuestions.get(j);
            j++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of keeping QuestionsDone, I suggest to keep QuestionAvailable (i.e. not yet answered), as indices of questions in the library

```
  List<Integer> availableQuestions = null;

  ...................................................

  if (startNumber == -1) {
        if (availableQuestions.isEmpty()) {
            finishQuiz(); 
            availableQuestions = null;
        } else {
             if (availableQuestions == null) {
                 // Starting a new quiz
                 availableQuestions = new List<Integer>(maxQuestions);
                 for (int i=0; i<maxQuestons; i++) availableQuestions.Add(i);
              }

            int nQuestionOrder = (int) (Math.random() * availableQuestions.size());

            nQuestionNumber = availableQuestions.get(nQuestionOrder);
            availableQuestions.removeAt(nQuestionOrder);  

        }
    }
```